# MySQL SUM on a query with mutiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum, fusioncharts

I have the following query:

`$strQuery = "SELECT siteid, SUM(watts) AS wattage, unit, device, time FROM inverter WHERE siteid = '528' AND time Between '$time1' AND '$time2' Order By device Asc";`

I'm making a graph in fusion charts and need the total watts for each device but when i do the query above it takes all values and places them for just the first device. I have 40 devices and need each one to have its total watts produced.

On the chart i am displaying device as the x axis name label and the wattage as the value.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SUM()` is an aggregate function which should be used together with a `GROUP` statement. If `GROUP` statement is omitted, all selected rows are aggregated as a group.

see docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Look into `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT siteid, device, 
  SUM(watts) AS wattage, 
  MIN(time) as start_time, 
  MAX(time) as end_time 
  unit
FROM inverter
WHERE siteid = '528' 
  AND time BETWEEN '$time1' AND '$time2'
GROUP BY device, unit
ORDER BY device ASC
```

Also, when you use aggregation and select fields that are not contained in the `GROUP` statement (here: time) you must make sure you really get the value you want.

The values of the aggregated row you get for each device are calculated using many rows with possibly individual values in those fields. When you don't use an aggregate function  (`MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, ..) to determine which of the multiple values your aggregated row should contain, you will receive a value selected more or less selected randomly by MySQL.

You should either

- do not select such field, when not necessary. (e.g. time)
- use an appropriate aggregate function (`MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, ..) for each field that is not contained in the GROUP BY clause to ensure you get the right value. (here i inserted both start and end time for the measure timespan using `MIN` and `MAX`)
- or include it in the `GROUP BY` clause 
  (i did that for "unit" in the example, because you get a wrong result when using `SUM` on both megawatts and kilowatts .. i assume that is what you use "unit" for?)

Again: Otherwise the resulting value in such fields is random and not deterministic.

Comment: You said: "with maybe individual values", you meant: "with **definitely** individual values" :-)

Comment: @Johan no i *definitely* meant *possibly*. ;-) for example, location may always be the same, assumed the devices are fixed and not moved around. (bad database normalization here, by the way). Also, "unit" may always be "kilowatts".

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the naive query as proposed by @Kaii and @cairnz.

However, **if** there are multiple times and units for the devices selected, MySQL will just select a unit and time from one device more or less at random.

**Why your query failed**
Use are using a aggregate function.
Unless you specify a `group by` clause the aggregate function will simple add all rows into 1 aggregate.
All the rows not covered in an aggregate function will be condensed into one item (one will simple be chosen at leasure).

In order to see what data lies underneigh, I suggest doing:

```
SELECT 
  siteid
  , SUM(watts) AS wattage
  , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT unit) as units
  , device
  , GROUP_CONCAT(time) as times 
FROM inverter 
WHERE siteid = '528' 
  AND time BETWEEN '$time1' AND '$time2' 
GROUP BY device
ORDER BY device ASC
```

The aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT` will show a comma separated list of all (DISTINCT) values lumped together by the aggregation.
Because you are only grouping by `device`, you will different kinds of `unit`s and `time`s will be lumped together.
The more columns you add to the `group by` clause the more you will "zoom in" on the data and the more rows will be shown.

**Why you should be careful in listing 'naked' columns in the select that are not in the `group by`**
If you list 'naked' columns (i.e. not as part of an aggregate expression) that are not listed in the `group by` clause **and** these columns are not functionally dependent on the group by clause.
There will be multiple different values, of which only one will be shown.
This behavior is unique to MySQL, most other SQL flavors will issue an error and refuse.

The reason MySQL allows this *dangerous* behavior is that
A: it allows for faster queries,
B: if you specify a unique key in the group by clause, the other fields will be functionally dependent on that key (cf ANSI SQL 2003) and specifying more fields makes no sense,
C: sometimes you don't care about the values of those other fields and displaying a random representative is what you want.

**Why can't I just list all non-aggregate columns in the group by**
If you alter the `group by` statement, this has a profound effect on the output.
The more columns (up until the point where you hit a unique key for the selected columns) you `group by`, the more details you get, which negates the whole point of using aggregate functions.

**The solution**
If you just want to show a random unit and time, that's cool of course, but perhaps it makes more sense to use the following query:

```
SELECT 
  siteid
  , SUM(watts) AS wattage
  , COUNT(*) as NumberOfUnits
  , device
  , MIN(time) as Mintime
  , MAX(time) as Maxtime
FROM inverter 
WHERE siteid = '528' 
  AND time BETWEEN '$time1' AND '$time2' 
GROUP BY device
ORDER BY device ASC
```

Creative use of the aggregate functions at your disposal is the answer, see:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Because you're using MySQL, I esp. recommend studying `GROUP_CONCAT` a very versatile and useful function.

Comment: Doesnt `COUNT(*) as NumberOfUnits` show the number of rows in the resultset? If so, wouldn't it show the number of time measures * units ?

Comment: +1 though for very elaborate explanations and additional information regarding mysqlspecific and group by

Comment: @cairnz, `count(*)` shows the number of rows, as does `count(unit)`, `count(distinct unit)` shows the number of different units used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell what to group by:

```
SELECT 
 siteid, 
 SUM(watts) AS wattage, 
 unit, 
 device, 
 MIN(time) AS StartTime,
 MAX(time) AS EndTime

FROM inverter 

WHERE siteid = '528' AND time Between '$time1' AND '$time2' 
GROUP BY siteid, unit, device
Order By device Asc
```

EDIT: Using `MIN()` and `MAX()` for time allows you to see which timespans the `SUM()` covers. You should not use time by itself in the query without specifying what time for the sum of wattage for the unit/device combination is showing.

Comment: +1 for MIN() and MAX() .. but you should explain to him why you mpdified the query that way.

Comment: You don't need to group by `siteid` here, there can be only one value and listing it will just slow things down.

Comment: @Johan, that's right, however i didn't spend much time looking at that, i was more interested in showing a different grouping.